# Fastest way to store and search large number of data in Java

Tags: java, xml, search, hashmap

Overall background of the problem.

I have 3 large XML files. In the first XML file, there is roughly 8000 IP addresses which I'm interested which I have split between 3 HashMap based on their properties. 
One HashMap is `<String, String>` while the other two are `<String, String[]>`.

An IP calculator gives me a list of IP's within a subnet as Strings which I then search through the 3 HashMaps to find matches. Once found I save them into another 3 HashMaps.

Now i need to search the other two XML files for these IP addresses. However 
other two XML's only have String references of the IP's.

So basically my question is, What is the fastest way to do a String search? I'm potentially looking at 100k comparisons which is going to be mega slow.

Any advice?

Comment: have you thought about using a database?

Comment: @JamesClark The question specifically says "IN JAVA"

Comment: @John Java can use databases.

Comment: @John - Um, you don't thing JDBC is Java?

Comment: Databases are not fast, at least not for things that fit into main memory.

Comment: @DonRoby Java can use a lot of things. What is your point.

Comment: @TedHopp I could show you how to write a little algorithm in Python and execute it in Java, but we both know the question has nothing to do with either Python or JDBC and was oriented towards a more vanilla Java implementation (at least more vanilla than introducing a database just to compare strings).

Answer (score 0):

Read in the xml to main memory, and do the search there.
If there are only String referecnes then introduce an own integer reference.
And initialize that once.
That way you should be very fast, much faster than any database.

Comment: We have read the XML into memory, Not sure how to introduce the integer reference though as the XML was badly formatted and has become bit of a challenge just to pull the information we need out.

Comment: Use own classes not the one generated by the XML importer. In that own class add one field "int refToTableX" and initailize that fields.